Does optional<reference_wrapper> not return a reference?
I wanted to make a Table class that is supposed to work like a table with columns and rows, and values in the cells. Obviously I need a function that would allow to get the value from a particular cell. I wanted this function (operator() in my case) to return a reference, so that it would be easy to change the cell's contents.
Now, I wanted to check in this function whether or not such a cell exists (i.e. are there enough columns and rows in the table). The problem is, I can't just return something like a nullptr if col/row index is out of bounds in a function that returns a reference.
I've read some other topics on SO and people suggested using optional<reference_wrapper>. Now, the problem is, I can't assign anything to the returned value. Here's the code:
class Table {
public:
    class Column {
    public:
        std::string Header;
        int Index = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> colCells;
        Column(std::string colHeader) { Header = colHeader; }
    };

    std::vector<Column> Columns;
    
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> operator()(int col, int row) {
        return Columns[col].colCells[row];
    }

    void AddColumn(std::string colHeader) {
        Column col(colHeader);
        col.Index = Columns.size();
        Columns.push_back(col);
        for (auto& row : Columns[0].colCells) { //for each row in the first column (we created a column first, so there's at least this one)
            col.colCells.push_back("");         //create a cell with an empty string    
        }
    }
    void AddRow() {
        for (auto& col : Columns) {
            col.colCells.push_back("");     //add empty string at the end of each column
        }
    }
};

AddColumn and AddRow methods aren't important here, I guess, but I just pasted them here for the code to be complete.
Now, I tried this:
data::tbl(4, 0) = "Col: 2, Row: 0";

And that's the errors I get. It seems as if this wasn't an actual reference to the cell's data. I should add that everything works fine the same way if I don't use optional and have the operator

What is happening and why?
PS. I know that another way to do all that, would be to change the return value to a pointer. But then I would have to dereference the returned pointer everywhere in the code like this:
*data::tbl(4, 0) = "Col: 2, Row: 0";

Which is something I'd rather avoid if possible.

std::optional also has to be dereferenced. It cannot provide direct access to underlying object, since it may be nullopt (like pointer can be nullptr).

Thanks. But, still, nothing changes in the error after dereferencing - the errors are exactly the same.

The errors cannot be exactly the same, because types change. Do note that dereferencing has lower precedence than function call operator, so it should be (*data::tbl)(4, 0). But that doesn't solve your main problem, this is no different than returning a pointer and suffers from the same problem of potentially dereferencing null.

Just don't do it. You are basically arguing that a reference can't be a nullptr, so you're adding all that extra work to create a reference with a bool to indicate whether it's even a valid reference. Really, if you need a "doesn't exist" result, a pointer will do just fine. Another alternative, especially if this is just meant to be an error-checking mechanic, is to return a reference or throw an error.

Ok, so all in all, I'm going to either stick to the pointers or rethink the whole design. But, considering that you have to dereference the return value of std::reference_wrapper>, why does it even exists? Isn't it always better (I mean, simpler - you don't need to #include <optional>) to just use pointers then?

@MarcinPagórek yes indeed, I haven't used the wrappers yet. But, I'm sure, there exists a useful use somewhere out there. Maybe, some day, I'll find myself typing std::reference_wrapper into some code myself.

@ChristianStieber What do you mean that an alternative is to return a reference? A reference to what?
When it comes to throwing an error - I considered that, but if columns/rows are out of bounds and I throw an error, then the program will stop working anyway, right? So that's not such a great solution, as I would just rather inform the user that it was out of bounds and then return sth like a nullptr.

@MarcinPagórek Why would the program stop? Exceptions can be caught... although, in general, I'd still expect them to be somewhat exceptional. If you're just using them in a elaborate if (hasItem) .. else ... style, they are likely not the right tool.

You may want to make a step or two back and ask "what should be my strategy for reporting errors" instead. And the answer to that is anything but "invent your own" (unless your goal is to invent a better-than-state-of-the-art error handling strategy). Look at std::vector. Does it return std::optional or anything? No, it either throws an exception or ignores the situation completely, leading to UB for which then the user can be blamed. Why not do the same? Or, since you are using std::vector, why not let it report (or ignore) the error?
